# compare array against array and delete element

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of items fed through the state from `const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);` response var. I'm trying to accomplish a "delete all selected items" functionality". How I'm trying to do this, I have a state array called `const [tobeDeleted, setTobeDeleted] = useState([])`. Every time I select an item, the `id` of that selected item is pushed to this array and vice versa if I unselect the item, its removed from the array.

Now what I want to achieve is that when you select an item and click the `Remove selected products` button and trigger the `removeAll` function, I want **this function** to check against both arrays the `response` array, the `toBeDeleted` array and filter the `response` array to remove every item with the `ids` present in the `toBeDeleted` array. I have accomplished an array that checks against each other but I'm not sure how to go about the delete part. Can someone help me out please?

Thank you, I have provided a working codeandsandbox for more clarity.

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-butterfly-vy6v8?file=/src/components/Dashboard.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified `removeAll` function:

```
const removeAll = () => {
    const newRes = response.filter((f) => !deleteItems.includes(f.productId));
    setResponse(newRes);
    setDeleteItems([]);
  };
```

Working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-khorana-lh9w5).

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
    const filteredResponse = response.filter((element)=> !toBeDeleted.includes(element.id) )
```

considering response has the following structure:

```
   [
    {
     id: .......,
     ......
    },
    .......
   ]
```

if response is just an array of ids then it will be **element** and not **element.id**.
Later you can set response to filteredResponse, to re-render.